# Using google data API

Tags: python, google-contacts-api

I want to learn google contacts API to manipulate my gmail contacts. I have two gmail accounts, one is for my regular use, the other for test purpose. However, when I run the [example code](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/samples/contacts/)(I wrote it based on contacts_example.py), I find that I can use the first account, but not the second.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
try:
  gd_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(source='GoogleInc-ContactsPythonSample-1')
  gd_client.ClientLogin(user, pw, gd_client.source)
except gdata.client.BadAuthentication:
  print 'Invalid user credentials given.'
  return
```

When I run it I get this, and I swear my password is right.

```
Please enter your username: drizzlexsi@gmail.com
Password:
Invalid user credentials given.
```

Any idea what can lead to this error? I think it has something to do with my test account, but I am not sure what is it.

Comment: Did you grant the app to access that information with your second account? could you provide the exception message? instead of the message you wrote.

Comment: It turns out that there is something wrong with my test account. I changed to another account and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an account setting in Google which makes this work.

Go to https://myaccount.google.com/ on your account that doesn't work and under the "Account settings -> Signing in" section there is a thing called "Less secure apps".  Click on "Turn on".  It should now work.

The direct page for this is https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

I hope that helps